# Symfony2 & Doctrine: Order entites by foreign attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I would like to use a select to get an array of entities with Doctrines QueryBuilder. But I need an `ORDER BY` which uses a foreign attribute (attribute in a table related with a foreign key). What I would like to write intuitively is something like this:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:relation_table');

$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('r')
 ->orderBy('r.fevent.date', 'DESC')
 ->getQuery();
```

Which, not surprisingly, doesn't work. In SQL my `SELECT` looks like this:

```
SELECT r.* FROM relation_table AS r
INNER JOIN events AS e
    ON e.IDevent = r.Fevent
ORDER BY e.date
```

But I also need Doctrine to give me the entity-object back. I think of two possible solutions:

1. Use the QueryBuilder to create an `INNER JOIN`, or
2. Create a free SQL Statement, same as above, and tell Doctrine somehow to create an entity object with its results.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: try to add a join like this : `->join('r.fevent', 'f')` and an `->addSelect('f')` and then your orderBy : `->orderBy('f.date', 'DESC')` (edit it with your fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the entity you want to order with:

```php
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->join('r.fevent', 'f')
    ->orderBy('f.date', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining both tables in your Doctrine Query (the first of your proposed solutions) is pretty straigtforward. Take a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#joining-to-related-records

A similar question was answered here: [Doctrine 2: How to search for an entity by its association's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933385/doctrine-2-how-to-search-for-an-entity-by-its-associations-value/9933727#9933727)